# switch and string literal characters in C

Tags: c

Take a look at the following example:

```
int main(){
        char *s = "Hello";
        switch (s[0]) {
                case "Hello"[0]:
                        return 1;
                case "Goodbye"[0]:
                        return 2;
                default:
                        return 0;
        }
}
```

When compiling this example, I get an error complaining about the case label not being an integer. But this seems incorrect as `"..."[0]` resolves to an integer.

Can someone shed some light on this and explain why this code doesn't compile?

Comment: My gut says it does not end up being a *compile time* integer constant.

Comment: +1.I too need an explanation for this question.`"Goodbye"[0]` seems to be `'G'` indeed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Case label needs to be an integer constant, not an integer expression. Although the expression  `"Hello"[0]`can be evaluated at compile time to `'H'`, the compiler is not required to do so.

> C99 standard, section 6.8.4.2, part 3:
>
> The expression of each case label shall be an integer constant expression and no two of the case constant expressions in the same switch statement shall have the same value after conversion.

Comment: "the compiler is not required to do so". Is this specific to `case` labels, or is compile-time evaluation optional throughout C?

Comment: But isn't `"Goodbye"[0]` the character constant **'G'**?After all **"Goodbye"** gives the base address of the string **constant** `Goodbye` and `"Goodbye"[0]` is nothing but **'G'**.Can you explain why still it gives error?I mean why `case 'G':` works but this doesn't.

Comment: `"Goodbye"[0]` is the result of a computation involving several steps: allocate some memory, put the string "Goodbye" in it, generate a pointer to it, and load the character that the pointer points to. Conceptually the last step can only happen at run-time, because it requires a running instance of the program to perform the load. Integer constants can't have any run-time operations in them, even if the results are theoretically predictable. `(int)(4*atan2(1,1))` can be predicted to evaluate to `3` but you better not try it as a `case` label.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley It's tempting to believe what you say as reasons you gave are good enough.Let's see what **dasblinkenlight** has to say.

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture WumpusQ.Wumbley is right, computing the value of `"Goodbye"[0]` requires allocating `"Goodbye"`, and taking the value at the initial address of the string literal, which is not considered a compile-time constant.

Answer (score 0):

"Hello" is a string literal.  If you want the first character of the string literal then you need to specify that, 'H' which is a single character.

The case statement can only be an integer or something that can be turned into an integer and it needs to be a constant at that.

See this tutorial on the switch statement.[enter link description here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson5.html)

Answer (score 0):

case labels should be constant expressions, that can be evaluated compile time.
Though seems logical, indexing into a string literal with a constant index is not a constant expression.

This goes back to the type system of C(++). Each expression has a static type. It is const char[] for a string literal, and as for any array, its value is a pointer, which can not be known at compile time.
It is filled in link time (think about the optimization that eliminates duplicated string literals), and most probably you will find the indirection in the generated code if global optimization does not resolve it.